# I wanted to understand the purpose of this code snippet

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Can someone please explain the purpose of this C# code. It's a code snippet in a Windows based application. 
Is it counting the number of keypress? What is the purpose of 13 here?

Any help would be much appreciated

```
 private void num2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
      if ((int) e.KeyChar != 13)
        return;
      this.Calculate();
    }
```

Comment: If enter presseed calculate else return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is unfortunately written - [`KeyPressEventArgs.KeyChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar) basically returns the character pressed (so shift-a will return 'A' for example). 13 is just the Unicode character for "carriage return" which is returned when the user hits return. I would have written that method as:

```
// Possibly rename to CalculateIfReturnIsPressed or something similar.
private void num2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Perform the calculation if the user hit return
    if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
    {
        Calculate();
    }
}
```

`\r` is the same character as `(char) 13`.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Why do you say unfortunate? Is it the coding style? Functionality wise both 13 and \r do the same job.

Comment: @Sandeep: It's unfortunate because it's going out of its way to cast to `int` and then using 13 which is less clear than `\r`. Basically, thinking of it as a `char` leads to a much clearer solution than thinking of it as an `int`.

Comment: I got it! Thanks Jon for explaining it

Answer (score 1):

If enter key pressed then go through calculate otherwise return...

if you dont want to use particular number then try this :

```
 if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
 this.Calculate();
 else
 return;
```

Answer (score 0):

`e.KeyChar = 13` i believe is Enter or Return key
So if the enter/return key is pressed it will do the `Calculate();` method, otherwise it will `return;`

Comment: It is the reverse. If an Enter is pressed then the Calculate is executed